# CSS opacity and transition break hyperlink on mobile device (iOS)

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a website with an image that redirects a user to another page (hyperlink). When you hover over the image, its opacity goes down to 50% using `opacity` and `transition`.

This works fine on a desktop, but on my iPhone (iOS 8) in Safari this is bugged. When you tap on the image, its opacity goes down but it does not register the touch (click). You have to tap the image again in order to make the hyperlink work and to be redirected.

This is my stylesheet:

```
a img {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
}

a img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

I have searched for similar questions on SO and Google, but none of the answers did it for me. For most, adding `visibility: visible;` seemed to do the trick, but not for me. It has no effect whatsoever. And as you can see it is in my CSS. (or I am doing something wrong here...)

I'll take any help I can, but I'd prefer some crafty CSS fix, and a way that avoids making platform-specific stylesheets.

**PS**. I know the hover is pointless on a touch device; this is merely a feature for desktop users, but I just don't want it to mess up a basic functionality on a mobile device.

Comment: Use modernizr and do not apply the transition on `.touch`. What you describe is just how it's supposed to work with `:hover`. http://modernizr.com/

Comment: @connexo Thanks for the comment and suggestion! I'd like to avoid including libraries (especially for mobile devices) to fix something that seems so simple :)

Comment: Nothing to fix here, it works as designed.

Comment: @connexo then not a fix but a workaround. I'd like to think I made it clear what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: You have your answer. If you don't want a library, you will have to implement touch detection by yourself.

Comment: I can't test here (because Android), but if it works as expected without the opacity and/or transition, why don't you put those properties in a media query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is simply to feed those styles only to larger screens, via a media query. E.g.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 30em) {
  a img {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
  }

  a img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a good solution that I can use. This won't fix the issue if it is viewed on high resolution touch devices though (e.g. AIO touch PCs), but I'll take it! I'll accept your answer soon if nothing better comes up :)

Comment: @Nic You can try to narrow the media query down by including the device type `handheld`. See [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#background).